# Silverlight - Play MediaElement at a time in a Storboard

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, timing, storyboard

I have a MediaElement that should be played at a certain point during a Storyboard (say 0.5 seconds in).  Is it possible to kick off MediaElements at any particular point in a Storyboard?  The Storyboard is set to repeat forever, so it should fire every time the marker reaches a certain time.